# Bayesian updating with Binomial data and a Uniform([0,$\theta$]) prior

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem

Assume $p$ has a $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$ prior, where $\theta\in(0,1)$ is a known constant. Let $X\sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What is posterior $\mu(p|X)$?

(In the $\theta=1$ case it's [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions) that $p|X=x\sim\text{Beta}(1+x,1+n-x)$. What happens when $\theta<1$?)

**Edit:** Assume for simplicity that this prior is correctly specified. (i.e. $p$ is "actually" drawn according to $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$, and then $X$ is drawn as above given $p$). However, if you know the answer for the case where this prior is *misspecified* (prior is $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$, but $p$ is actually drawn according to $\text{Uniform}([0,1])$) then even better!

Comment: If $X$ is the number of successes out of $n$ tries, it is either 0, 1 or above. If $\theta \in (0,1)$ then the uniform prior's support never includes 1 or any number above it. Has your prior ruled out every possible observation except zero? I don't think Bayes theorem behaves right when you observe something to which you've ascribed zero prior probability.

Comment: Very good question! 

For a fixed $\theta\in(0,1)$, the $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$ prior indeed means that $p\in(\theta,1]$ are "ruled out" ex-ante. I should have explicitly stated in my question that I assume this prior is correctly specified (i.e. $p$ is *actually* drawn according to the prior $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$)

Comment: P.S. This question is actually a stepping stone for figuring out the case where this prior is misspecified (i.e. the prior is $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$, but $p$ is "objectively" drawn according to $\text{Uniform}([0,\theta])$). 

(A seminal paper about this kind of learning is [Berk (1966)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-37/issue-1/Limiting-Behavior-of-Posterior-Distributions-when-the-Model-is-Incorrect/10.1214/aoms/1177699597.full))

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do the calculation:

$$p \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,\theta), \quad f(p) = \frac{1}{\theta} \mathbb 1(0 \le p \le \theta),$$ and $$X \mid p \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p),$$ so that $$f(p \mid x) \propto \Pr[X = x \mid p]f(p) = p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \mathbb 1(0 \le p \le \theta).$$  This is a truncated beta; to show this, we integrate with respect to $p$ to find the normalization constant that makes the posterior likelihood a proper density:

$$\int_{p=0}^\theta f(p \mid x) \, dp = \int_{p = 0}^\theta p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \, dp$$ which is an incomplete beta function.  For integers satisfying $0 \le x \le n$, there is a closed polynomial form; e.g., if $n = 7$ and $x = 3$, we get $\frac{\theta^4}{280}(70-224\theta+280\theta^2-160\theta^3+35\theta^4)$, and then the posterior density is $p^3(1-p)^4$ divided by this amount.  It is not difficult to write this polynomial in terms of a finite sum; e.g.,
$$\begin{align}
\int_{p=0}^\theta p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \, dp 
&= \int_{p=0}^\theta p^x \sum_{k=0}^{n-x} \binom{n-x}{k} (-p)^k \, dp \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-x} \binom{n-x}{k} (-1)^k \int_{p=0}^\theta p^{x+k} \, dp \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-x} \binom{n-x}{k} (-1)^k \frac{\theta^{x+k+1}}{x+k+1}. \end{align}$$ So an explicit answer for your posterior density would be:

$$f(p \mid x) = \frac{p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \mathbb 1(0 \le p \le \theta)}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-x} \binom{n-x}{k} (-1)^k \frac{\theta^{x+k+1}}{x+k+1}}.$$